# perl Gtk2 widget->foreach() with same values

Tags: perl, widget, gtk2

i'm creating a gtk2 based nftables config software, and heres my problem:

i have a HBox with no input at the beginning. then, the user can press the add button, so a first instance of a drop down list appears. i made a signal connect when the button is pressed and in the sub i create the drop down list. after all creation i pack the created thing to the Hbox and returns.
If the user clicks another time on the add button, another instance appears. At the end of all code all dropdown information should be read and put together.

my idea is to us the HBox->foreach() function and read the data with get_active_value().

But, after all, the string only contains the last value. when i print out the values while foreach, only the last value appears, too.

So, what is my fault?
Thank you very much for help ;)

**EDIT**
If i select "foo_1" and "foo_2" for the first vbox and "bar_1" and "bar_2" in the second one, the returned string only contains "bar_1 bar_2 bar_1 bar_2".
CODE

```
my $Hbox = Gtk2::HBox->new();

$button->signal_connect('clicked', sub {
   my $VBox = Gtk2::VBox->new();
   my $dropdown = Gtk2::ComboBox->new_text();
   my $dropdown_2 = Gtk2::ComboBox->new_text();
#... create some values ...
   $VBox->pack_start($dropdown,FALSE,FALSE,5);
   $VBox->pack_start($dropdown_2,FALSE,FALSE,5);
   $Hbox->pack_start($VBox, FALSE,FALSE,5);
})
...
my $final;
$HBox->foreach(sub {
    $final = $final.$dropdown->get_active_text().$dropdown_2->get_active_text();
}
);
print $final;
```

Comment: Does the `foreach` function need an anonymous subroutine? Also, it appears you may be missing a closing parentheses for the `foreach` function..